# WebLogic ERROR: No credential mapper entry found for password indirection user=db_user?

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.0

Every time I try to deploy my EJB service app to Weblogic 10.3 server, I get following error:

> java.security.PrivilegedActionException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: No credential mapper entry found for password indirection user=db_user for data source my_ds

How to solve this??

Comment: Hey Monzurul. Could you please accept the right answer for this question. Will benefit all those who will run into the same issue. Me being one of them :) . Thanks !!

Answer (score 10):

The [Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?forumID=83&threadID=928897) have posted a solution for this, if you are deploying to another Weblogic server other than the Integrated one with JDeveloper.

While generating ear file for an application from JDev, it will generate a *-jdbc.xml file for each DB connection in the application resources, set the indirect password attribute, update weblogic-application.xml to add each *-jdbc.xml file as a module and update web.xml (if it exists) to add a resource reference to each jdbc jndi name. However, since there is no server to deploy to, Jdev will not place the passwords in the ear file. The EAR file will not deploy as is. The passwords for the data sources must be setup on the server before the application will run correctly.

> 1. Right click on Application drop down select Application properties
> 2. Click on Deployment
> 3. Uncheck “Auto Generate and Synchronize weblogic-jdbc.xml Descriptors During Deployment”

Comment: In JDeveloper 11.1.2.3, there is no option to uncheck. You have to select `Deployment >> Weblogic`, then click a button to expose the option that can be unchecked.

Answer (score 7):

In JDeveloper 11.1.2.3 +
[9.3.4.2.1 Applications with JDBC Data Source for WebLogic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/web.111240/e17272/deploy_java_ee_app.htm#sthref117)

> If your application uses application-level JDBC data sources with
>   password indirection for database connections, you may need to create
>   credential maps in WebLogic Server to enable the database connection.
>   For more information, see Section 9.3.7, "[What You May Need to Know
>   About JDBC Data Source for Oracle WebLogic Server.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/web.111240/e17272/deploy_java_ee_app.htm#CHDIDBCG)"

OR

1. Open '**Application properties**'
2. Uncheck '**Auto Generate and Synchronize Weblogic JDBC Description During Deployment**'

[image]

Comment: I know this is an old post , but I have come across the same issue. What exactly does unchecking of this option do. Does this mean that data source information will not be mapped in the connection_name-jdbc.xml and web.xml.

Comment: In my case I am able to deploy to remote server when that is deselected, but it has to be selected when I'm deploying to my local weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem process as below mentioned

1-create a connection data source in weblogic and copy JNDI name.

2-Open Appmadule.xml file goto configuration and click AppmoduleLocal and paste 
  JNDI name 
  as DataSource name. Same as for AppModuleShare. Save the file

3-Go To Applicaton property and uncheck the option 'Auto Generate and Synchronize Weblogic JDBC Description During Deployment'.

4-Now go to deploy and run your application.