# Deployment Failed -weblogic.application.ModuleException

Tags: deployment, ejb, weblogic, oracle-adf, jta

I am developing an application in JDeveloper and I am trying to deploy the application to my WebLogic server but I see the following exception:

```
    <12-Dec-2015 16:58:24 o'clock EET> <Error> <JDBC> <BEA-001553> <Unable to deploy JDBC data source localhostXE. No credential mapper entry found for password indirection user hr> 
<12-Dec-2015 16:58:24 o'clock EET> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "105826237129178" for task "0". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: No credential mapper entry found for password indirection user=hr for data source localhostXE"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: No credential mapper entry found for password indirection user=hr for data source localhostXE
    at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:350)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.common.ResourceException: No credential mapper entry found for password indirection user=hr for data source localhostXE
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.getDriverProperties(DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.java:486)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig$2.run(DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.java:360)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.initJDBCParameters(DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.java:356)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<12-Dec-2015 16:58:24 o'clock EET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "Test01".> 
<12-Dec-2015 16:58:24 o'clock EET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.common.ResourceException: No credential mapper entry found for password indirection user=hr for data source localhostXE
    at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:350)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.common.ResourceException: No credential mapper entry found for password indirection user=hr for data source localhostXE
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.getDriverProperties(DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.java:486)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig$2.run(DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.java:360)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.initJDBCParameters(DataSourceConnectionPoolConfig.java:356)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Do you have any ideas about how I can repair the error, so that I can continue my work? I have read some things on Internet but nothing helped? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360871/weblogic-error-no-credential-mapper-entry-found-for-password-indirection-user-d ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have just tried to uncheck "Auto Generate and Synchronize Weblogic JDBC Description During Deployment" but there is no result.

Comment: Do you read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/web.111240/e17272/deploy_java_ee_app.htm#CHDIDBCG ?

Comment: Yes, It is very helpful article. My application is deployed with password indirection set to <true>. There is specified username in connection_name-jdbc.xml file and I am using JDeveloper to directly deploy the application to WebLogic server. It is said that JDeveloper automatically creates a credential mapping, but the error message from the log says: "No credential mapper entry found for password indirection user=hr for data source localhostXE". Any Ideas how to configure the problem? Thank you! :)